# reducing code lines with the use of MACROS

Tags: c

I have a doubt about MACROS. if i have the next code, which has a switch statement and inside that switch there are some cases(from 0 to 9),would it be possible if i try to reduce some code lines and use a MACRO named NUMBERS like this, instead of putting all those cases: case '0', case '1', case'2', case'3', etc..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUMBERS if(car >= 0 && car <= 9)

int main()
{
    char car = '0';
    function(car);
    return 0;
}

void function(char car)
{
    switch(car)
   {
       case NUMBER:
          printf("It is a number\n");
          break;
   }
}
```

thanks

Comment: You define NUMBERS then use NUMBER. Is that your actual code?

Answer (score 2):

A macro is (almost) a simple text substitution - as if you copied and pasted.

This:

```
#define NUMBERS if(car >= 0 && car <= 9)

... later ...

switch(car)
{
    case NUMBERS: // note NUMBERS, not NUMBER
        printf("It is a number\n");
        break;
}
```

is *exactly* equivalent to this:

```
switch(car)
{
    case if(car >= 0 && car <= 9):
        printf("It is a number\n");
        break;
}
```

and as you can see that is not valid syntax.

Comment: however `#define NUMBERS 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9` would work even though it is horrible.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah you would need to change `case NUMBERS:` to just `NUMBERS` as well. And it's horrible for production code, but it's useful for understanding macros.

Comment: Sorry I had already edited the comment but not before you saw it!

Comment: thanks for your answers i made i mistake it is NUMBERS instead of NUMBER, but the question remains, do you recommend to put a macro like this:  #define NUMBERS if(car >= 0 && car <=9)??

Comment: If you use macros for a while, you will learn when they are and aren't helpful. I would not recommend using that macro as I think it makes your code harder to read, but that's just my opinion (although I think a lot of people will agree). There is nothing technically stopping you using that macro.